# Filepicker.io ensure url select file is stored

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

Here's what my file picker looks like

```
filepicker.pick({
  mimetypes: ['image/*'],
  services: ['COMPUTER', 'URL'],
  maxSize: 5 * 1000 * 1024
}, function(FPFile) {
  // do stuff to file
});
```

The problem is that when a url select is chosen, instead of uploading the file to file picker the url is served directly. This makes storage unreliable because the external host can take the file down, etc.

Is there a simple way to ensure that when using the URL upload the file is directly hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for this.

The first of which is the Store API. When you receive the fpurl back, call the `store` api and this will save the file to your storage directly. This might be best if, for example, people can select files at will, but you only want to persist them when they choose to save something. e.g. when uploading for a new post. Why persist items if they don't decide to create a new post in the end?
https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store

The second option is to replace your `pick` call, with the `pickAndStore` call, which does both at once and saves you having to do the `store` command in your `pick` callback.
https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#pickAndStore

While `pickAndStore` may feel like it saves work, if there's a chance that you don't actualy need to persist data after a user picks it, then I'd go the extra distance with your own custom callbacks (this is where you'd create difference conversions too).

Comment: Thanks, seems like filepicker just added this, maybe even in response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the filepicker.store api - see https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store for more information

Comment: Shouldn't filepicker handle this automatically? Making another request on top of the request already made makes no sense. Plus wouldn't it store twice if you're using the direct upload option already.